# What is kafka connect Json Schema good for?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I wonder what is the benefit of adding the json schema to your message as kafka connect do support it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schemas are an important part of data pipelines. Kafka Connect supports embedding it in JSON, or you can use another option (Avro, Protobuf). If you don't have a schema you make life more difficult for consumers of the data, and some will insist on it—for example the JDBC Sink connector *requires* there be a schema and will fail if there isn't.

So to answer your question, if you don't want to use Avro or Protobuf (and if you like having large messages with lots of redundant repeating data ;-) then you can use Kafka Connect JSON schema format.